# CountVectorizer converts words to lower case

Tags: python, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

In my classification model, I need to maintain uppercase letters, but when I use sklearn countVectorizer to built the vocabulary, uppercase letters convert to lowercase!

To exclude implicit tokinization, I built a tokenizer which just pass the text without any operation ..

my code:

```
co = dict()

def tokenizeManu(txt):
    return txt.split()

def corpDict(x):
    print('1: ', x)
    count = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 1), tokenizer=tokenizeManu)
    countFit = count.fit_transform(x)
    vocab = count.get_feature_names()
    dist = np.sum(countFit.toarray(), axis=0)
    for tag, count in zip(vocab, dist):
        co[str(tag)] = count

x = ['I\'m John Dev', 'We are the only']

corpDict(x)
print(co)
```

the output:

```
1:  ["I'm John Dev", 'We are the only'] #<- before building the vocab.
{'john': 1, 'the': 1, 'we': 1, 'only': 1, 'dev': 1, "i'm": 1, 'are': 1} #<- after
```

Comment: Your example is not reproducible, please declare the dictionary `co`

Comment: Sorry, I edited it ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained in the documentation, [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html). `CountVectorizer` has a parameter `lowercase` that defaults to `True`. In order to disable this behavior, you need to set `lowercase=False` as follows:

```
count  = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 1), tokenizer=tokenizeManu, lowercase=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `lowercase` attribute to `False`

```
count = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 1), tokenizer=tokenizeManu,lowercase=False)
```

Here The Attributes of `CountVectorizer`

```
CountVectorizer(analyzer=u'word', binary=False, charset=None,
        charset_error=None, decode_error=u'strict',
        dtype=<type 'numpy.int64'>, encoding=u'utf-8', input=u'content',
        lowercase=True, max_df=1.0, max_features=None, min_df=0,
        ngram_range=(1, 1), preprocessor=None, stop_words=None,
        strip_accents=None, token_pattern=u'(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b',
        tokenizer=None, vocabulary=None)
```